# Custom Auto Numbering in receipt table by code in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, auto-increment

I need to auto Numbering the receipt data whenever I insert a new row data no increment in the mysql table its still remain the same receipt id 8874 
no idea were it get wrong

```
       if ($param1 == 'edit' && $param2 == 'do_update') {
        $data['op_number']   = $this->input->post('op_number');

        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');

        $data['ic']          = $this->input->post('ic');

        $data['receipt'] = '8800';
     for($i = 0; $i < 74; $i++) 
 {
$data['receipt']++;
if(substr($data['receipt'], 5) == '100')
{
  continue;
}
}      

        $this->db->insert('invoice', $data);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message',       get_phrase('invoice_created'));

        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?receptionist/manage_invoice', 'refresh');
```

Comment: Your column is named  receipt and is autoincrement in your db?

Comment: no because i have already have autoincrement id in database the receipt is to generate auto-numbering for customer bill any solution for this?

Comment: You can change the field to autoincrement and set what the next increment value should be. Much easier and safer than the approach used above.

Comment: i need two field to be increment

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
$receipt = '8800';

for($i = 0; $i < 74; $i++){
    $receipt++;
    if(substr($receipt, 5) == '100'){
    continue;
    }
}

if ($param1 == 'edit' && $param2 == 'do_update') {
$data= array{
'op_number'  = $this->input->post('op_number'),
'name'       = $this->input->post('name'),
'ic'         = $this->input->post('ic'),
'receipt' = $receipt };




$this->db->insert('invoice', $data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message',get_phrase('invoice_created'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?receptionist/manage_invoice', 'refresh');
```